# How do you notify that you edited your question if was put _on hold_?

Tags: support, questions, flagging

I asked a question and it turns out now is [on hold] because 'it's unclear what I asked'

I edited hoping the unclear step was that but I am not sure if it was that.

How do you notify the people who put your question [on hold] that you edited and also to ask them to specify which part is not clear?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Taking a tour of our [help] would benefit you, now that you have joined several SE sites.  That will answer a lot of questions you might have concerning how SE works.

Comment: @whuber thank you

Comment: @whuber I've read https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4689 as you suggested. It turns out I edited before asking this question. Could you please take a look at my question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/391199/estimation-of-parameter-hat-beta-in-the-linear-model